# How to intergrate scriptcam plugin to capturing and saving video to server using ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a requirement to record video using webcam and save to server using ruby on rails.
I have seen scriptcam-rails gem but couldn't get any idea how to use that in my applicaiton.
Is there any solution to do that in rails ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked for me. Below are the steps.

Firstly copy the scriptcam js files to your **app/assets/javascripts** folder or directly map from your view using html src tag

Secondly and most important copy the **scriptcam.swf** file to your **public** folder.
Thats it now restart your server and start recording!!!